# Embed 3 view controllers inside scrollview

Tags: swift

I'd like to add 3 view controllers inside a scrollview (snapchat style). The following code seems to work fine, but when I exit the app (go to the home screen), and come back, the views resize for some odd reason. I tried adding alignAllTop and alignAllBottom but to no success. Any ideas why this could be happening?

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    self.mainScrollView.delaysContentTouches = false

    let v1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileViewController") as! profileViewController

    self.addChildViewController(v1)
    self.mainScrollView.addSubview(v1.view)
    v1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    //--------

    let v2 : recordViewController = recordViewController(nibName: "recordViewController", bundle: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(v2)
    self.mainScrollView.addSubview(v2.view)
    v2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    //--------

    let v3 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "discoverViewController") as! discoverViewController

    self.addChildViewController(v3)
    self.mainScrollView.addSubview(v3.view)
    v3.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


    //--------
    var v1frame : CGRect = self.mainScrollView.bounds
    v1frame.origin.x = 0
    v1.view.frame = v1frame

    var v2frame : CGRect = self.mainScrollView.bounds
    v2frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    v2.view.frame = v2frame

    var v3frame : CGRect = self.mainScrollView.bounds
    v3frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width*2
    v3.view.frame = v3frame

    //v1.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let csH1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-[v]-|", options: [.alignAllTop], metrics: [:], views: ["v": v1.view])
    let csH2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-[v]-|", options: [.alignAllTop], metrics: [:], views: ["v": v2.view])
    let csH3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-[v]-|", options: [.alignAllTop], metrics: [:], views: ["v": v3.view])

    let csB1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-[v]-|", options: [.alignAllBottom], metrics: [:], views: ["v": v1.view])
    let csB2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-[v]-|", options: [.alignAllBottom], metrics: [:], views: ["v": v2.view])
    let csB3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-[v]-|", options: [.alignAllBottom], metrics: [:], views: ["v": v3.view])

    self.mainScrollView.addConstraints(csH1)
    self.mainScrollView.addConstraints(csH2)
    self.mainScrollView.addConstraints(csH3)

    self.mainScrollView.addConstraints(csB1)
    self.mainScrollView.addConstraints(csB2)
    self.mainScrollView.addConstraints(csB3)



    //UI
    self.mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 3, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    self.mainScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width, y: 0), animated: false)
```

Comment: I suggest you to try visual debugger. [Here](http://imgur.com/a/Z9sYK) are two two screenshots:
(1) click this button below editor in Xcode - it activates visual debug of your running app
(2) Check if there's purple rectangle with a number at the top status bar (not sure if it's called so) of Xcode. If it is there then it means you have autolayout issues.

Comment: @DaniyarKarbayev there are no errors. And even if there were, why would this happen only when I reopen the app?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend in your storyboard inside view controller add one scrollView pinned all the constraint(leading, trailing, top, bottom) and then add subview inside scrollView. Now pinned your subView constraint with respect to scrollView (leading, trailing, top, bottom, equal Width(should be equal to or greater than to), equal height (should be equal to or greater than to).

For Horizontal scroll
If you wanted to scrolling horizontally then also pinned width constraint, this is required to avoid auto layout error but inside placeholder checked Remove at build time.

For Vertical scroll
If you wanted to scrolling vertically then also pinned height constraint, this is required to avoid auto layout error
 but inside placeholder checked Remove at build time.

Note:- You can use either both or any one

After that add three subView inside your subView and pinned its constraint accordingly.

Finally, load your three view controllers on the three subview.

In this approach it will be easier to maintain you do not have to handle much code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to constraint your subviews to UIScrollView's content which means that you'll need to add 4 horizontal constraints:

1. Leftmost view should have left edge equal to superview
2. Second view should have left edge equal to first view's right edge and right edge equal to third view's left edge.
3. Rightmost (third) view should have its right edge equal to superview.

Comment: tried, doesn't work. Doing so disables scrolling on the scrollview for some reason